# How to convert tf.layers.optimize_loss from TF 1.x to TF 2.x?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to use the tf.layers.optimize_loss module from TF 1.x in TF 2.x but I don't find the module. Can you help me? Thanks !
The code is:

```
optimizer = tf.layers.optimize_loss(loss, tf.train.get_global_step(),
                                                        self.learning_rate,
                                                        'Adam',
                                                        name='Optimizer')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf_slim library.

```
import tf_slim as slim
optimizer = slim.optimize_loss(loss, tf.train.get_global_step(),
                               self.learning_rate, 'Adam', name='Optimizer')
```

[Here is the link of github repository](https://github.com/google-research/tf-slim/blob/77b441267e27359e94a641b906f07afc25f69b13/tf_slim/layers/optimizers.py#L58)